# Approaching SASS refactoring in an automated manner: duplication, nesting

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am in charge of reviewing a website's SASS code, SASS syntax.

The code has a lot of duplication and several levels of nesting. My intention would be to refactor, clean duplication, simplify, possibly abstracting repetitions, possibly modularize, etc.

Manually attempting to find all duplicated rules in this highly nested code is proving difficult and not very efficient.

How can I approach this task in a more automated manner ?

The code compiles to a single minified css file using sass, autoprefixer and cssnano on Gulp.

I am working on Sublime 3.

Thank you